# getting sum of a column using CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, jpa, criteria, criteria-api

I am trying to get a Sum of amount using criteria (Criteria Builder and CriteriaQuery)

But I am getting a error when I am writing the code;
Here is my code

```
    public Long findAmountByCriteria(OrderCriteria orderCriteria) {

  final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
  final CriteriaQuery<BigDecimal> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(BigDecimal.class);
  Root<Order> root = query.from(Order.class);

  query.select(criteriaBuilder.sum(root.get("amount")))
  .where(buildPredicateForOrderResponseCriteria(criteriaBuilder, orderCriteria, root));

  final TypedQuery<BigDecimal> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query);
  return typedQuery.getSingleResult().longValue();
}
```

Amount is in a BigDecimal value.

in select mehtod it says,

```
The method select(Selection<? extends BigDecimal>) in the type CriteriaQuery<BigDecimal> is not applicable for the arguments (Expression<Object>)
```

in sum method

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method sum(Expression<N>) of type CriteriaBuilder is not applicable for the arguments (Path<Object>). The inferred type Object is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <N extends Number>
```

How can I fix this problem.

Answer (score 2):

instead of what your are doing

```
query.select(criteriaBuilder.sum(root.get("amount")))
```

try doing this

```
query.select(criteriaBuilder.sum(root.<BigDecimal> get("amount")))
```

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR

> Sum of amount using criteria

You need to pass proper expression, to do so you should pass the [CriteriaQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html) with numeric type to the criteria builder.

```html
public class Aggregate<T, S extends Number> {
    public Aggregate(Class<T> tableType, Class<S> type) {
        this.criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        this.criteria = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(type);
        this.root = criteria.from(tableType);
    }

    public Aggregate<T, S> aggregate(String field) {
        criteria.select(criteriaBuilder.sum(root.get(field)));
        return this;
    }

    public <I> Aggregate<T, S> restrict(String field, I i) {
        criteria.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(field), i));
        return this;
    }

    public S perform() {
        return entityManager.createQuery(criteria).getSingleResult();
    }

    private Root<T> root;

    private final CriteriaQuery<S> criteria;

    private final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder;
}
```